# How to handle extra requirements when also used as type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, setuptools, python-importlib

I want to update a library so that a requirement is optional (using [`extras_require`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)).

Unfortunately, imported classes from the optional requirement are used everywhere in the lib as type hints. Here is an example:

```py
from typing import List
try:
    from extra.sub import ExtraFoo, ExtraBar
except ImportError:
    pass

def optional(foo: ExtraFoo) -> List[ExtraBar]:
    pass

def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    greeting('John Smith')
```

In this example, we won't use `optional()` if `extra` was not installed. Indeed, such code will raise a `NameError` since `ExtraFoo` and `ExtraBar` are used as a type hint.

A possible fix is to declare `class ExtraFoo: pass` and `class ExtraBar: pass` in the `except` block. However, there are situations like that everywhere in the code with multiple types from the same module.

I'd like to avoid polluting the code with declaration of dummy imports. Is there a common way to deal with this situation (e.g. a proxy module)?

Comment: I am not sure I am following how it is an issue, I am probably missing the point. Who, or which tool is complaining about the missing `Frame` type?

Comment: `List["Frame"]`? Besides using literal strings, you can move the type hints into a stub file or declare the package a required dependency.

Comment: @sinoroc I changed the example to make it less confusing.

Comment: @DurandA Alright, this triggers an error at runtime, I had indeed missed the point. I had assumed a tool like _mypy_ was complaining. hoefling's suggestion seems like a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it with [typing.TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING)

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
   from extra.sub import ExtraFoo, ExtraBar
```

If you need the imports for something else than type hints you need to import them in a regular way, either in the function that need them.

```
try:
    from extra.sub import ExtraFoo, ExtraBar
except ImportError:
    ExtraFoo = None
    ExtraBar = None

def function_that_need_extra_foo():
    if ExtraFoo is None:
       raise ... # Error that states ExtraFoo is not available
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the original question is included in the comments, however it's a bit confusing as the question has been edited. For the current version of the question, I believe the solution is to use forward references, i.e. put your type hints in quotes as follows:

```py
def optional(foo: "ExtraFoo") -> List["ExtraBar"]:
    pass
```